# I tried with this table can any one help in design

Tags: tables, extreme-tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{A Section}
\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\caption{The Caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{Instances} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{no protection} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ protection}\\ \hline

Networks & K \multicolumn{2}{|c}{ILP} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Greedy} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{ILP} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{Greedy} \\ \hline 

& & & S & T & S & T & S & T \\ \hline 


NFNET & 5 10 & 3 5 & 200 400 & 300 500 & 4 8 & 600 900 & 5 8 & 921 633 & 5 4  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{A Second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please format your source in a more usable manner, look at newlines for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point with `booktabs`. I don't quite like it, but a) it compiles, b) it is not entirely clear to me, what the table should convey, hence it's not clear what cells should be grouped together.

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,multicol}

\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},kerning=true,spacing=true,tracking=true,final]{microtype} %% pdflatex
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench} %% just because

\begin{document}

\title{Title} \maketitle

\section{A Section} \lipsum

\begin{table*} \caption{The Caption} \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{18}{c}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Instances} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{no protection} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{protection}  \\
%        \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Networks} & \multirow{2}{*}{K} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ILP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Greedy} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ILP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Greedy} \\
                                  & & & S & T & S & T & S & T \\
        \midrule
    NFNET & 5 10 & 3 5 & 200 400 & 300 500 & 4 8 & 600 900 & 5 8 & 921 633 & 5 4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular} \end{table*}

\section{A Second Section} \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to format your table as in your question, I suggest to use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. However, I think that a design in the spirit of `booktabs` will be better.

```
 \documentclass[]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table*}
 \caption{The Caption}
 \centering
 \begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{c}}[vlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
 \Hline
 \Block{1-2}{Instances} && \Block{1-4}{no protection} &&&& \Block{1-4}{protection}\\ \Hline
 \Block{2-1}{Networks} & \Block{2-1}{K} & \Block{1-2}{ILP} && \Block{1-2}{Greedy} && \Block{1-2}{ILP} && 
 \Block{1-2}{Greedy} \\  \Hline
 & & S & T & S & T & S & T & S & T \\ \Hline  
 \Block{2-1}{NFNET} & 5  & 3 & 200 & 300 & 4 & 600 & 5 & 921 & 5 \\[-1pt]
                    & 10 & 5 & 400 & 500 & 8 & 900 & 8 & 633 & 4 \\ \Hline
 \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table*}

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you @F. Pantigny , unfortunately i got erorr in usepackage nice matrix, cell-space-limits is unknown can you guide me how to resolve this ..

Comment: Thanks @albert but how can i make it as narraw as possible? I cant do it wide like what you posted,

Comment: @Qussy A. Ameer. I think you don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation. If you use Overleaf, you have to upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can download that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: +! very nice as usual